# Where can I find the fields of the posts, returned by WP_Query?

Tags: wordpress

Lets say I use `$query = new WP_Query( arguments );` or `$worksArray = get_posts( args );`

where can I find the available fields of the returned list so I know what to get from a post?

```
foreach ($worksArray as $work) {
  $work->ID
}
```

What else there is in the $work object besides the id?
I can't find a class diagram/reference of the returned type. The codexs' documents say `it returns the list of posts` but there is no link to see **what** do this posts can be or what fields are there.

(example: `$work->the_title()`, `$work->something_else`)

Comment: aren't there ANY documents at all???? it is a post type of 'post'. There should be documents

Comment: Look e.g. in the `get_posts()` documentation: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post#Return

Answer (score 1):

From the page: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post#Return

**The fields returned are:**

```
ID (integer) The post ID 
post_author (integer) The post author's ID 
post_date (string) The datetime of the post (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS) 
post_date_gmt (string) The GMT datetime of the post (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS) 
post_content (string) The post's contents 
post_title (string) The post's title 
post_category (integer) The post category's ID.
post_excerpt (string) The post excerpt 
post_status (string) The post status
comment_status (string) The comment status (open|closed|registered_only) 
ping_status (string) The pingback/trackback status (open|closed) 
post_password (string) The post password 
post_name (string) The post's URL slug 
to_ping (string) URLs to be pinged 
pinged (string) URLs already pinged 
post_modified (string) The last modified datetime of the post
post_modified_gmt (string) The last modified GMT datetime of the post
post_content_filtered (string) 
post_parent (integer) The parent post's ID (for attachments, etc) 
guid (string) A link to the post. 
menu_order (integer) 
post_type (string) (post|page|attachment) 
post_mime_type (string) Mime Type (for attachments, etc) 
comment_count (integer) Number of comments
```